# How to write a for loop which runs an asynchronous command in each iteration?

Tags: bash

I wonder why there is an error using an asynchronous command within a loop?

```
$ for i in {1..8}; do sleep 100 & ; done
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

If I write it as

```
$ for i in {1..8}; do 
> sleep 100 & 
> done
```

this works fine.

How can I write it in one line without error?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Drop the `;`:

```
for i in {1..8}; do sleep 100 & done
```

[`&` separates commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Lists), so the `;` is extraneous (and the shell expects something between `&` and `;`).

Comment: Thanks. "the shell expects something between & and ;", so why isn't an empty command ok between & and ;?

Comment: POSIX [mentions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xcu_chap02.html#tag_23_02_09) that empty commands are “silently unspecified”, but that “conforming applications do not construct empty commands”. Bash doesn’t allow empty commands; some other shells do.

Comment: The real no-op command is :

Comment: @StephenKitt, the section you reference also states: "In an interactive session or a script with other commands, extra <newline> or <semicolon> characters...would not qualify as the empty command described here because they would be consumed by other parts of the grammar."  Hmmm...

Comment: @Wildcard that’s interesting, I hadn’t thought through the consequences of that sentence when researching the answer to Tim’s follow-up. Enabling Bash’s POSIX mode doesn’t change its behaviour in this regard. Hmmm indeed...

Comment: @Wildcard: `echo foo ; ; echo bar` in bash 4.4 says `syntax error near unexpected token \`;'`.  `dash` gives a similar error.  In this case, it is an empty command because no other part of the grammar consumes it.  I think they might be talking about redundant `;` at the end of a line like `sleep 100;` (newline).

Answer (score 24):

[Group](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html) your `do` actions in curly brackets:

```
for i in {1..8}; do { sleep 100 & }; done
```

Easy to understand for you as well as for Bash!